# Beamer presentation similar to ConTeXt

Tags: beamer, context

I am wondering if it would be possible to write nice (different and funny) presentations with `beamer` like the ones that can be found in the next links, that are done with `context`. I also wonder if it would take too much effort to achieve the same or similar result.

http://www.leverkruid.eu/context/DIC-EuroTeX-presentation.pdf

ftp://ftp.pet.au.dk/pub/gilbert/context/pragma-ade/collect/present/pre-ntsx.pdf

ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texcollection/2008/context/docroot/documents/collect/present/pre-educ.pdf

ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texcollection/2008/context/docroot/documents/collect/present/pre-pdf1.pdf

ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texcollection/2008/context/docroot/documents/collect/present/pre-idea.pdf

ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texcollection/2008/context/docroot/documents/collect/present/pre-ntsa.pdf

ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texcollection/2008/context/docroot/documents/collect/present/pre-ntsb.pdf

Thanks

Comment: Probably you are right... :(

Answer (score 1):

The beamer package seems not flexible enough for those kind of layouts, it was designed for more traditional slide shows in mind. You're probably better off designing the slides manually with the help of a graphics package, e.g. TikZ.